# Font-size responsive on query-selector

Tags: jquery-selectors, font-size

I have read through other questions and tried to make my text become responsive past a certain breakpoint.  But when I save it does not scale it just takes my font-size: 60px; value. Min-width means if the px value is greater than or equal to and vice versa for max-width correct?  So in theory, this should work?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    .et_pb_text_2 h3{
       font-size: 60px;
   }
    .et_pb_text_5 h3{
       font-size: 60px;
   }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px){
    .et_pb_text_2 h3{
       font-size: 4vw!important;
   }
    .et_pb_text_5 h3{
       font-size: 4vw!important;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please explain which problem you are facing or share your html?
I have created html for it and it works nicely.

Below 1024px screens, font-size will be 4vw. It means that the font size will be only 4 percent of viewport width whenever screen size is below 1024px.Whenever screen size is equal to or greater than 1024px it will stick to 60px.

See below code and it is working perfectly.

```css
.et_pb_text_2, .et_pb_text_5 {
    display: inline-block;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px){
  
 .et_pb_text_2 h3{
    font-size: 60px;
  }
  .et_pb_text_5 h3{
    font-size: 60px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px){
  .et_pb_text_2 h3{
    font-size: 4vw!important;
  }
  .et_pb_text_5 h3{
    font-size: 4vw!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="et_pb_text_2">
  <h3>Hello</h3>
</div>
<div class="et_pb_text_5">
  <h3>World</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: the website is at seniorlivingmedia.com.  And the headings are on the front page, in the yellow then white containers. It is really strange.